# Why does reading a file in PHP not work for me?

Tags: php

It was supposed to be a simple login, but only recognizes one password. Why?
In password.txt it says:

```
moin
britta
pialo1217
```

in master-pwd.txt:

```
paul1210
```

But the script accepts only britta. However, with the others I just do not get any feedback. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? I am an absolute beginner. Please do not overwhelm me directly.
Here my Script:

```
    <?php
        $seiteninhalt = "";
        $eingabe = $_POST["passwort"];
        $seiteninhalt .= $eingabe;
        $filename = file("passwort.txt");
        for($i=0;$i < count($filename); $i++){
            //echo $filename[$i];
            if ($filename[$i] == $eingabe){
                echo "Korrekte Eingabe!";       //Successfull --> normal login
            }
        }
        $filename = file("master-pwd.txt");
        for($i=0;$i < count($filename); $i++){
             //echo $filename[$i];
            if ($filename[$i] == $eingabe){
                echo "Korrekte Eingabe! Voller zugriff!";  //Successfull --> Master login
            }
        }
        //echo $seiteninhalt;
    ?>
```

Comment: `file` splits a file per line, are those passwords on separate lines or the same one?

Comment: This isn't for anything web based, is it?  Storing passwords as plain text in an obviously named text file is pretty risky.

Answer (score 1):

From `file()` documentation:

> Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, *with the
> newline still attached*.

You are probably comparing "moin" to "moin\n" or "moin\r\n". You can use `trim()` or `rtrim()` to get rid of those newline-characters. Or you can use `file(..., FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)` as suggested in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As Roman mentioned in his answer, the reason this isn't working is because `file` adds newlines to the end of each element in the array. You could put this code into a function to simplify your code:

```
<?php

function check_password($filename, $password)
{
    $passwords = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    if (in_array($password, $passwords))
        return true;
    return false;
}

$password_to_check = 'moin';

if (check_password('master-pwd.txt', $password_to_check)) {
    echo 'Master login!';
} else if (check_password('passwort.txt', $password_to_check)) {
    echo 'Normal login!';
} else {
    echo 'Password failed!';
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant.

Comment: You could shorten the function by `return in_array($password, $passwords);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are not closing access to the previous file, instead try this (I do not know if it will work as I am using very old version of PHP)

```
 <?php
        $seiteninhalt = "";
        $eingabe = $_POST["passwort"];
        $seiteninhalt .= $eingabe;
        $filename = fopen("passwort.txt");
        for($i=0;$i < count($filename); $i++){
            //echo $filename[$i];
            if ($filename[$i] == $eingabe){
                echo "Korrekte Eingabe!";       //Successfull --> normal login
            }
        }
        fclose($filename);

        $filename = fopen("master-pwd.txt");
        for($i=0;$i < count($filename); $i++){
             //echo $filename[$i];
            if ($filename[$i] == $eingabe){
                echo "Korrekte Eingabe! Voller zugriff!";  //Successfull --> Master login
            }
        }
        //echo $seiteninhalt;
        fclose($filename);
    ?>
```